# Doctrine: Many to many query gives incomplete results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Ok, I got three tables 'articles', 'tags' and 'articles_tags', with a many-to-many relationship between the first two.

Now I'm trying to query "Find me all articles with the tag with ID 3"

I've been trying this:

```
$query = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("a", "t")
            ->from("Models\Article", "a")
            ->leftJoin("a.tags", "t")
            ->where("t.id = :tagid")
            ->setParameter("tagid", $_GET['id'])
            ->getQuery();
$articles = $query->getResult();
```

That does find the correct articles alright, but those articles now only show as having the one tag even if they have many more.

I feel like I made a silly mistake somewhere, or maybe chose the completely wrong approach, but I've been staring at it, and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I suggest you to select only the article entity in the query then access the tag using the entity relation (something like `$article->getTags()`)

Comment: Yes, but then I'd have to do a `foreach` on the articles array, and filter out only those I need. That's fine if I got only 10 entities in the database not when it's a lot more. Or am I misunderstanding this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest

```
$query = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("a")
            ->from("Models\Article", "a")
            ->join("a.tags", "t")
            ->where("t.id = :tagid")
            ->setParameter("tagid", $_GET['id'])
            ->getQuery();
$articles = $query->getResult();

// Because IN clause throw an exception with empty array
if(count(articles) === 0) {
   return [];
}

$query = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("a")
            ->from("Models\Article", "a")
            ->where("a.id IN (:articles)")
            ->setParameter("articles", $articles)
            ->getQuery();
return $query->getResult();
```